# page has two tool bars

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am starting the NavigationPage in the App.cs class:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PageA());
```

In PageA(), I am are calling "PushAsync":

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCourseList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());
    }
}
```

If I click back button on PageB(), it goes to PageA() in which it has two tool bars.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please show the picture about two tool bars, does it often happen?

Comment: Could you show the code of pageB as well please. Why do you navigate to pageA from your App.cs if your page is called MainPage?

Comment: The error usually happens when you have a double navigation page calls somehow idk what you are doing but the reason must be that and i have a way to not get into that and i have posted the same in the answer below which you can check goodluck

Comment: Yes @G.hakim. That was a mistake, i had two navigation calls. Sorry guys and thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it is very simple you are providing two navigation pages in the page lifecycle which is in turn showing two Navbar's

Solution :

In your App.xaml.cs add a static NavigationPage property something like this:

```
public static NavigationPage NavigationPage { get; set; }
```

Assign this a Page in your app.xaml constructor something like this :

```
App.NavigationPage = new NavigationPage(new yourPage) ;
```

Then Assign this NavigationPage as your MainPage like this:

```
MainPage=App.NavigationPage;
```

Now Whenever you plan on going to the next page call the next page like this:

```
App.NavigationPage.PushAsync(new YourNewPage());
```

Goodluck!

In case of queries revert.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct for other people to find it please